# Login Problem as SYSDBA ORA-01031

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have the following problem:
I can connect to an Orcale database as normal user or as sysdba:

```
sqlplus myuser/myPw@myDB

sqlplus "sys/sysPw@myDB as sysdba"
```

But when another (Windows-User) is logged on, he could only use

```
sqlplus myuser/myPw@myDB
```

With

```
sqlplus "sys/sysPw@myDB as sysdba"
```

he gets the error:

> SQL*Plus: Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production on Do Sep 29 12:10:07 2011
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2002, Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> ERROR: ORA-01031: Nicht ausreichende Berechtigungen.

I even tried full qualified paths to sqlplus with the same result.

**Edit:**

I see the possibility that different windows users use different (windows-) environment variables, especially different PATH variables. 
Further I see the possibility that some windows dlls could have wrong security settings and can not be accessed by one of the users.

But I do not see, how this could make an Oracle user, ( SYS in this case ) behave differently.

**2nd Edit:**

I checked that the Path variable is a system variable, i.e. both windows logins use the same paths.

Comment: Are you sure "mydb" points to the same database? Check tnsnames for example.

Comment: Yes I use the TNS_ADMIN environment variable cf. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3194/how-to-handle-multiple-oracle-homes/3195#3195

Comment: All the same, I'd be inclined to prove it beyond doubt with the 'myuser' connection that does appear to connect on both machines - eg create a dummy table and select from it on the other machine. Also is either machine you are connecting from also the server or are they both windows clients?

Comment: It is the same remote machine to which I connect using two different windows accounts.

Comment: Have you done any connection [logging](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14212/troublestng.htm#i423153)?

Comment: That seems to be the right hint. I found fresh log entries

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your ORAPWD file? Maybe the initial originator of the database set entries=1. That would allow 1 user to logon as SYSDBA and the second user would not be able to logon as SYSDBA. Just a thought  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your init.ora parameter REMOTE_LOGIN_PASSWORDFILE is set to "exclusive".

Answer (score 1):

Are you really connecting via

`sqlplus sys@db as sysdba`

as opposed to

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

? For the latter, the Windows account should be in the ora_dba group, see
[Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b32010/authen.htm)